# EF Core 2.0 Migrations issue

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I'm creating a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 project (SDK 2.1.2) with EF Core and when adding migrations, the generated code is unable to compile due to not being able to resolve *SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy*.  This class looks to be part of the **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata** namespace, which should be contained in the **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** assembly.  However I can not  seem to resolve this issue.  My project's csproj file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore\2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational\2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Based on the above project file, the SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy enum should be resolved (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore) but VS2017 is still complaining.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces and assemblies are different things. In particular namespaces can be shared between assemblies.

In this case, the [`SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.sqlservervaluegenerationstrategy?view=efcore-2.0) enum is indeed contained in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata` *namespace*, but as you can see from the link, is defined in **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll** *assembly*.

Comment: I missed that 2nd line for some reason.  Thanks!